# Does migration from VB6 to Vb.net supports backward compatibility?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

An interop COM application was developed in VB6 and recently we had migrated from VB6 to VB.NET.

For example, I have a server code. When VB6 server code is registered and then if we run VB6 client code, it works perfectly. Then I had registered VB.net server and if I run VB.net client, it works perfectly.

Now if I go back and open original VB6 client, it is giving me an error and it doesn't open. Error is"unable to start, quitting".

Is VB.net to vb6 backward compatibility not possible?

Using VB6Server:

- Basic VB6 Active X Server---> Consumed in VB6ServerClient

Using VBNETServerReplica:

- VB.Net Active X Server
- Copied COM GUID from VB6KevinServer
- RegAsm    ****.Exe /codebase /tlb
- Consumed in VBNETServerReplicaClient
- Original VB6ServerClient FAILED !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vb6 to vb.net dll compatibility version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31246808/11683)

Comment: You didn't even post what the error was.  Give us something to go on...

Comment: Error is"unable to start, quitting"

Comment: It is probably insufficient to just use a single COM GUID. That's not enough to guarantee that the COM signature of one DLL exactly matches the original. You need to exactly implement the entire set of interfaces that are being consumed. As a starting point you could look at how the VB6 code imports into Visual Studio and make sure you are matching that. Also using OLEView to inspect the type library would be a good idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vb6 to vb.net dll compatibility version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246808/vb6-to-vb-net-dll-compatibility-version)

Comment: "Is VB.net to vb6 backward compatibility not possible?" Yes, it is. It's called "binary compatibility." It's discussed in Chapter 9 of the free MSDN PDF book "Upgrading Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 to Microsoft Visual Basic .NET."